# Error in TCMPublisher.exe with debug mode

Tags: publishing, content-manager

I am trying to start publisher windows service but getting error, unable to solve them.
I have tried running the TCMPublihser.exe /debug mode and i get some progress but i get following error

> Error when calling method 'GetDeploymentNotification' of the object 'cd_transport.Transport'.
>   Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {FDD3F879-14B4-4492-9A45-B640B3EA3E07} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800706b5.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the Transport service is started.

Check in event log also the cd transport log to see if there are more details. Did it start failing after changing the Java version? Ensure you have all the libs and the appropriate (64bit) version of the DLLs.

Comment: Transport service is not started, when i try to start transport service it give error "Transport service started and then stopped, some services  automatically stops if they are not in use by other applications". Java version on command prompt is "1.6.0_26" 64 bit, I had Java 1.7 but somebody told me to delete that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your transport service is not happy. You are likely to have some additional errors in the Windows Event log (check under Tridion and under System or Applications).

Very likely, there's a problem with Java (Transport service is a Java service).

I would try the following:

1. Make sure java is correctly installed. Type `java -version` on a command prompt, check if that actually gives you anything
2. Repair the Tridion install

If this is a new machine, you may also just try rebuilding the box. If you follow the steps as [outlined by Alvin](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2013/tutorials/creating-development-vm-1.aspx) you should get it to work correctly.